# Share a Chrome Profile with VMWare on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, vmware-fusion

I would like to share my work-Mac Chrome profile from "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome" with the Windows 7 installation in VMWare, so I can use the same browser on both machines.

Unfortunately, using native Google Sync is not an option as I already use that for my private machine.